# String together data from input box into string

Tags: php, string

I have 3 input boxes with the following data

```
<input name="day" type="text" id="day" class="required" maxlength="2" minlength="2" style="width:60px;"> - <input name="mth" type="text" id="mth" class="required" maxlength="2" minlength="2" style="width:60px;"> - <input name="yr" type="text" id="yr" class="required" maxlength="4" minlength="4" style="width:100px;">
```

which when pulling using my php I want to convert to a string so I can do some stuff with it.

This is what I have so far

```
$dob = $data['yr'] + "-" + $data['mth'] + "-" + $data['day'];
```

But that's returning 2016! Could anyone please tell me what I need to do to make it display as 0000-00-00 as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript uses `+` for concatenation PHP uses `.`

`$dob = $data['yr'] . "-" . $data['mth'] . "-" . $data['day'];`

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much. I'm moving from ASP.net. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$dob = $data['yr'] ."-" .$data['mth'] ."-" .$data['day'];
```

if you want to concatenate in php use . operation you are using + oprerand which is used in javascript to concatenate

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much. I'm moving from ASP.net. :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, if you want to get the string as a result, use cancatenate operator . as (dot) is used in php for cancatenation.like
$dob = $data['yr'] ."-" .$data['mth'] ."-" .$data['day'];

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much. I'm moving from ASP.net. :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is that when you use + in php it converts your string data to numeric data which can be rather confusing for thouse who use other programming languages (for example in python) , to concatanate strings use . instead of +.